# Are there limit problems that cannot be solved?

Tags: limits

This could mean any of the following:

the limit is unsolvable by algebraic means or by hand (rationalizing or limit laws or squeeze theorem)

the limit is unknown

inspired by:

http://socrates.bmcc.cuny.edu/math/Mzyman/CalcLab2-303.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean "solve a limit" by calculating the specific value of it, the answer is yes; and there are perhaps a lot more limits than you can calculate by algebraic means.

Consider the following infinite series when $s$ is positive 
$$ \zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s} $$

We know that $\zeta(1)$ diverges. How about other values of s? They are not easily calculable; most of them requires advanced knowledge in mathematics. For example, $\zeta(2)$ equals $\frac{\pi}{6}$, while the limit itself suggests no connection with $pi$. This surprising result can be proved by multiple methods, the one I know requires some knowledge in Fourier analysis. Until now, we have for even integers $2n$,
$$\zeta (2n)={\frac {(-1)^{n+1}B_{2n}(2\pi )^{2n}}{2(2n)!}} $$

But no general expression has been yet found for odd, or even rational numbers.

Many mathematicians were devoted to study $\zeta(s)$, which is related to the famous unsolved mathematical problem, the Riemann Hypothesis.

Comment: @DonAntonio apologies, that's a typo

Comment: @R You could as well have writtent that $\;\zeta(s)\;$ converges iff  Re$(s)>1\;$

Comment: ahh, the Bessel problem

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_n$ be the number of times the digit $9$ appears in the first $n$ digits of the decimal expansion of $\pi$. What is
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}?
$$